# ¿Cómo configuro variables de entorno en Django?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Estoy trabajando en una pequeña aplicación en Django.

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo configurar variables de entorno para unas Api Keys de autenticacion en `virtualenv` para Windows. Solo encuentro referencias para configurar en Linux.

Answer (score 3):

En realidad, crear una variable de entorno es algo que se hace de forma similar en sistemas operativos tipo *nix y en Windows, pero hay algunas alternativas que te pueden ayudar.

1. **Agregar las variables al activar el entorno**.
   Puedes agregar las variables en el archivo `activate` o `activate.bat` creado en tu entorno virtual. De modo que cuando se active, también se activen las variables que quieres. Este archivo es un script *shell* en *nix y un archivo de lotes en Windows, así que solo sigue las instrucciones para tu caso particular.
2. **Usa Django Environ (*recomendado*)**
   Seguramente hay otros paquetes que hacen este trabajo, pero [Django-environ](http://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) es el que yo uso y recomiendo. Aquí creas un archivo (generalmente llamado `.env`) y contiene todos los pares clave-valor que se convertirán en variables de entorno.

   Por ejemplo, solo tendrías que crear un archivo con la claves. Así:

   ```
   API_CLIENT=kCG825f
   API_SECRET='!T#O|-W8rI)(Y~ heg6_Ypvn|>zemyz*V|+R}+|-^$0N8),w2r_jQ6s]DiRYS|7-'
   ```

   Y después de activar `environ` en tu proyecto, usarías así esas variables en, por ejemplo, el archivo `settings.py`:

   ```
   API_CLIENT = env('API_CLIENT')
   API_SECRET = env('API_SECRET')
   ```

Las dos opciones son igualmente efectivas, pero la segunda me parece más eficiente.

Comment: gracias toledano voy a tenerlo muy en cuenta y gracias por tu tiempo para responder soy nuevo en esto de django y aveces me cuesta